# mysql INTERVAL по временным меткам

Tags: mysql, interval

Подскажите, как правильно решить данное задание?
Пробовал и так, и через DATE_SUB, выдаёт 0 человек, хотя их точно несколько.

В таблице users есть поле activity_date, которое хранит дату и время последней активности пользователя на сайте. Посчитайте сколько пользователей находилось на сайте 8 апреля 2018 года в 12:36:17.
Данные выведите в колонке с именем users.
Считайте, что пользователь находился на сайте, если он совершал какие-то действия в последние 5 минут до контрольного времени.

SELECT COUNT(id) as users
FROM users
WHERE DATE(activity_date) = '2018-04-08' AND TIME(activity_date) = '12:17:36' - INTERVAL 5  MINUTE

OUTPUT: users
0

Comment: *OUTPUT: users 0* Ясен пень. Тебе требуется не количество юзеров, которые проявили активность РОВНО 5 минут назад, а теч, которые её проявили НЕ БОЛЕЕ 5 минут назад. То есть и 2 минуты, и 3, и 15 секунд... Надо брать все записи в диапазоне от заданной даты-времени минус 5 минут и до заданной включительно. Оператор BETWEEN. И, чтобы не получить ерунды, надо отдельные дату и время собрать в одно значение, иначе получишь хрень для значений, когда указанный 5-минутный интервал захватывает полночь и смену даты.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)))